# Why does the TextBox in visual c# keep removing and adding itself?

Tags: c#, textbox, controls

I've been trying to create a windows form application where I programmatically create a TextBox after certain conditions are met. However, when I run the code, for some reason, the code works as if there were no if statements. I've tried to add more conditions to prevent that, and I've also tried looking if any conditions were found to be true when it should have been false. I don't know what to do. Here is my code:

```cs
private void fmaEquation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get whether any textboxes hold any of these strings
    bool f = IfVarIsThere("f");
    bool m = IfVarIsThere("m");
    bool a = IfVarIsThere("a");
    // if textbox has not been added but 2 of 3 variables are given
    Console.WriteLine("F: " + f + " M: " + m + " A: " + a + " eqNum: " + eqNum + " Contains? " + this.Controls.Contains(eq[eqNum]));
    if (!(this.Controls.Contains(eq[eqNum])) && ((f && m) || (m && a) || (f && a)))
    {
        eq[eqNum] = new TextBox();
        eq[eqNum].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10 + 3 * txtSize, 30 + eqNum * 20);
        eq[eqNum].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(txtSize, 10);
        this.Controls.Add(eq[eqNum]);
        eq[eqNum].Text = "f = m * a";
    }
    // else, if the textbox is there, but 2 of 3 variables are not there
    else if ( !((f && m) || (m && a) || (f && a)) && this.Controls.Contains(eq[eqNum]))
    {
       this.Controls.Remove(eq[eqNum]);
    }
}

private bool ifVarIsThere(String s) // loop through array to see whether String s is in any of the variable textboxes
{
    for (int i = 0; i < varNum; i++)
    {
        if (var[i].Text.ToLower() == s)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For some reason, the textbox will add itself, then delete itself, then re-add itself and repeat in a never ending cycle. I'm also running this method in the background.

Comment: The text box doesn’t “do” anything to itself like that. What is the code doing to the text box? I would suspect the “Add” and “Remove” calls are related..

Comment: @user2864740 , I **agree.** The problem is **probably** coming from the "Add" and "Remove" calls.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The windows form application keeps re-adding and deleting the text box. this.Controls.Add(Control) will add that Control to a list. this.Controls.Contains(Control object) will determine whether the Control is within a list. this.Controls.Remove(Control) will remove that Control form the list. I hope this helps!

Comment: I checked by replacing else if ( !((f && m) || (m && a) || (f && a)) && this.Controls.Contains(eq[eqNum])) with else if (!(f && m)) but nothing changed

Comment: What does eq eqNum and var mean?

Comment: Is there any code is calling `Controls.Add` or `Remove` or calling `fmaEquation` somewhere else. That could be the issue.

Comment: I checked whether contains? would be false, true, false, true, but it the output was only false the entire way

Comment: i do use Application.Idle += fmaEquation(); under the form constructor

Comment: eq is an array of TextBoxes, while eqNum is the index of the strings. however, I don't have any code yet that changes the value of eqNum

Comment: The simplest way to find the root problem is to simplify your `if` `elseif` blocks. Start very simple and work your way to your end version. It appear be just a logical error.

Comment: When I used else if (!(f && m)) and tested it with just "f" and "m" the situation didn't change

Comment: the code actually used to be much simpler, but I had to add conditions to try to keep my if statements in check, but of course, that didn't work :(

Comment: what event triggers the `fmaEquation` method?

Comment: my if statement used to be this: if ((f && m) || (m && a) || (f && a)))

Comment: eqNum is the index of the textboxes, my bad

Comment: @Barns the method is an idle method; it will be triggered when an event has just finished, to update itself (I just figured out what @ means, still new here)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Idle is the event you want here.  Idle fires whenever a Thread goes into an Idle state.  If you proceed to go off this event and the mess with the Form, it is going to change state and then come back and be Idle again, causing an infinite loop as you add controls.

Then since you add a text box with literally the text "f = m + a", the next time around you will always trigger the Remove logic because the box you just added had the text you were looking for.

I would either go off some other event or else you have to remove this line:

```
eq[eqNum].Text = "f = m * a";
```

Comment: Thanks, but the string "f = m * a" is not the same as "f", "m", or "a". I don't understand. Could you explain that further please?

Comment: !((f && m) || (m && a) || (f && a)) && this.Controls.Contains(eq[eqNum])  ->

! (false || false || false) && true -> !(false) && true => true && true.  This means that you'll always hit the else. :)